# Erro ao chamar item de tabela no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho uma `View` no laravel que mostra a chave de acesso e a chave secreta da `api` do usuário, essas duas chaves são puxadas do banco de dados para a `View`, eu quero poder editar somente a chave de acesso quando for necessário uma mudança, porém estou tendo o seguinte ***erro*** nas `Views`:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$api_secret_Key

Segue os controllers que estou usando:

Controller que retorna para a view da API (mostra as chaves):

```
public function index()
{ 
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $user = DB::select("select * from users where id = '$id'");
    return view('users.API', compact('user'));
}
```

`Controller` `edit` e `update`:

```
public function edit(User $user)
{
    return view('users.editApi', compact('user'));
}

public function update(UserRequest $request,  User $user)
{   
    $user->update($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('api.index');
}
```

como estes controllers são chamados:

Edit:

```
@foreach($user as $user)
<input class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="api_access_key" id="input-name" type="text" value="{{ $user->api_access_Key }}" readonly="readonly required="true" aria-required="true"/>  
</div>
<a href="{{ route('api.edit', $user->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __('Editar') }}</a>
@endforeach
```

Update:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('api.update', $user) }}" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: O problema me parece ocorrer nesse trecho `value="{{ $user->api_access_Key }}"`, **`$user` tem essa propriedade `api_access_Key` ?**, note que o `K` de key esta em maiúscula

Comment: Por gentileza, provoque o erro e copie o texto completo. Quero saber se o erro é na view, no model ou no controller.

Comment: `$id = Auth::user()->id; $user = DB::select("select * from users where id = '$id'");` essas duas linhas são desnecessarias, poderia utilizar assim `$user = Auth::user()` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeitos corretos de usar seus códigos:

```
use Auth;
use App\User;
public function index()
{ 
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $users = DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->first(); //Dessa forma pega primeiro registro caso queira todo troque por get()
    return view('users.API', compact('users'));
}

public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    return view('users.editApi', compact('user'));
}

public function update(Request $request)
{   
    //Caso passe $id na rota do update só tirar $request->id e passar o $id que vem da rota.
    $user = User::find($request->id);
    $user->dados = $request->dados; // Exemplo de como usar continue com todos dados
    $user->save();
    return redirect()->route('api.index');
}
```

Exemplo de foreach:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<input class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="api_access_key" id="input-name" type="text" value="{{ $user->api_access_Key }}" readonly="readonly required="true" aria-required="true"/>  
</div>
<a href="{{ route('api.edit', $user->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __('Editar') }}</a>
@endforeach
```